# virtualmin doesn't allow me to access database

Tags: virtualmin

I'm really new to `virtualmin` and the company that I've work for ask me to implement a wordpress website on a specific server of the client.

when I login in his account there's no database there and I can't add a new one. but the server has an existing wordpress website but as far as I know when you install wordpress you need database. I don't know how the client did this. I've check several tutorials in youtube on how to access the database but all I see is that it is already there on the dashboard.

here's my dashboard I can't see the edit database tab there and I don't know why.

I've come across this thread

https://www.virtualmin.com/node/18161

saying that it won't allow me to add new database if the database used was outside of virtualmin.

so my question is how can I enable the `edit database` tab on my dashboard.

and I've check the `wp_config.php` of the existing wp site and it points me to virtualmin... Still I don't know why I can't view the `edit databases` tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The administrator of the server needs to grant database access for your account. There are several privileges related to databases; the administrator can find that by selecting the domain account in question, then cicking *Administrative Options->Edit Owner Limits*. In that form, there's a section labeled *Allowed capabilities and features*. The specific option to enable is called *Can manage databases*. There are also configurable limits, such as the number of databases you can create, and similar.

[image: Editing owner limits in Virtualmin]

As for databases created outside of Virtualmin, the root/administrative user can import them to be under management by a given Virtualmin domain account in *Edit Databases->Import Database*.

Comment: but the problem is that I only have 1 user and it should have full control over the dashboard. as you can see on my image there that's the only tab that I can access. I don't know why though..

Comment: These changes need to be made by a root-level user on the server. These are privileges granted by the root user; unless you have root level access to the system, you can't change these privileges yourself.

Comment: yes and my user is a root-level user. but the problem is that I can't see some tabs there..

Comment: That looks like a Virtualmin domain account user, and not a root-level user. Are you actually logging in with username "root" (or a system user account that has sudo ALL privileges)? A domain account has limited privileges, and the root user can grant additional privileges. If you have root level access to the system, you need to login with the root user in order to grant privileges you want to the virtualmin domain account...otherwise, whoever does have root will need to do so.

Comment: If you have root ssh access, or a sudo-capable user account (it needs to have a line that looks something like this "username  ALL=(ALL)  ALL", in order to be considered a root user by Webmin), you should login with that user rather than the domain owner user, in order to make these privilege changes. If that doesn't work in Webmin for some reason, it's possible to create a new root-level user in Webmin from the command line, but that's kinda tricky...I suspect you just need to talk to the administrator of the server to get these privileges granted to your virtualmin domain account.

Comment: yes sir, I'm also guessing that the credentials that he gave me isn't a root level user. which is why it is restricted on some functionalities... thanks... so I guess the account that he gave me is not a root user level.  thanks again

Comment: when I go to edit user tab. my login access is only Email, FTP and SSH and Database is ALL.., DAV = yes.. what I understand is that I can access the database however I can't find the edit database tab... I'm really confused..

Comment: That's not confusing: You don't have the right privileges to manage databases. The privilege needs to be granted to your user, as I showed in the answer above (including a screenshot for exactly how/where this needs to happen). Everything is behaving as designed. Whoever gave you the account needs to also grant the privileges you need to do your job. ;-)

Comment: thanks alot sir.., so I need the root level user to grant my account that I'm using a privilege to access the database.

Comment: Update or change the password. Perhaps the first character or the last character, or just update / enter the same password.
Make sure you don't have the same user with the same name, with a different host.

maybe through the virtualmin panel and I advise you to repeat the process in PHPmyadmin.

It worked for me!